# How to validate decimal with comma for Input onChangeText React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, validation

I need to validate number with two decimal in `TextInput` (React Native) to prevent the insertion of the second comma.
Right now I can enter 123,12,23 and it breaks the app.

```
export default class Bottom extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      sum:'',
    }
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(value) {
     // validation of the value
     this.setState({sum: value});
   }
 render () {
    return ( 
      <View>
       <TextInput 
        style={styles.input} 
        keyboardType ="decimal-pad"
        autoCorrect={false}
        placeholder='add'
        onChangeText={ this.handleInputChange }
        value={this.state.sum} 
       />
      </View> 
    );
  }
```

I tried to use `indexOf` but it deletes the first comma, not the second

```
if (value.indexOf(',') === -1) {
 this.setState({sum: value});
```

Any suggestions or link to right answers?

**Update**

**I've resolved it:**

```
handleInputChange(value) {
    let lastValid = this.state.sum;
    //var validNumber = new RegExp(/^\d*\.?\d*$/); // for dot
    var validNumber = new RegExp(/^\d*\,?\d*$/); // for comma
      if (validNumber.test(value)) {
        lastValid = value;
      } else {
        value = this.state.sum;
      }
    this.setState({ sum: lastValid });
  }
```

Sandbox updated as well

Sandbox:https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-blackwell-208p6?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this: add `onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}` to your `TextInput`, then:

```
handleKeyPress(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) || charCode != 188)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.value.match(/,.*,/g) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Your input element is not accepting such values?

Comment: I added sandbox above, could you check it?

Comment: You have to remove the hardcoded `value={this.state.sum}` at `<input/>`, that's causing the lock

Comment: if I remove it how then it will validate the input? that is I entered 123,55,8899 ... I need a second comma not to be allowed to enter.

Comment: Your `onChangeText()` passes the value to `handleInputChange()`, if you set the input's value explicitly, you'd block it's ability to change it (which is the point of an input field). Ok, so now you clarified your expectations - I'll edit my answer in a minute (if it helps, please mark it as correct answer).

Comment: thanks for your efforts. I've already solved it and I've posted it in my question update. Moreover the solution is for React Native, not for PC keyboard.